# Decoding the binary part of a Discovery udp packet payload for Tp-Link Tapo c200 IoT IP camera

Tags: encryption, udp, wireshark, ip-camera, autodiscovery

I'm trying to figure out the API stack of this tplink C200 camera, it's not publicly available. I could figure out most of the Api calls with relative ease using fiddler and Wireshark, but a bit of binary frame in the beginning of a discovery call is baffling me.

Camera's android App starts broadcasting this udp packet to 255.255.255.255 as soon as user logged in for the first time:

```
0000   ff ff ff ff ff ff 20 4e 7f d9 64 3e 08 00 45 00   ...... N..d>..E.
0010   02 11 08 88 40 00 40 11 b0 46 c0 a8 bf 65 ff ff   ....@.@..F...e..
0020   ff ff cd ed 4e 22 01 fd 1e c3 02 00 00 01 01 e5   ....N"..........
0030   11 00 08 34 d4 be c1 46 b6 89 7b 22 70 61 72 61   ...4...F..{"para
0040   6d 73 22 3a 7b 22 72 73 61 5f 6b 65 79 22 3a 22   ms":{"rsa_key":"
0050   2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 50 55 42 4c 49   -----BEGIN PUBLI
0060   43 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 5c 6e 4d 49 49 42   C KEY-----\nMIIB
0070   49 6a 41 4e 42 67 6b 71 68 6b 69 47 39 77 30 42   IjANBgkqhkiG9w0B
0080   41 51 45 46 41 41 4f 43 41 51 38 41 4d 49 49 42   AQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB
0090   43 67 4b 43 41 51 45 41 33 72 4e 70 4f 66 6b 59   CgKCAQEA3rNpOfkY
00a0   35 35 4d 6a 32 62 6c 77 4e 39 6d 30 5c 6e 62 56   55Mj2blwN9m0\nbV
00b0   50 72 79 76 32 37 68 6c 61 7a 6f 46 37 78 4d 55   Pryv27hlazoF7xMU
00c0   46 4f 46 57 6b 62 63 61 6f 4a 41 67 6e 52 79 45   FOFWkbcaoJAgnRyE
00d0   36 42 56 30 77 70 47 71 68 79 4f 69 49 4f 72 34   6BV0wpGqhyOiIOr4
00e0   35 50 49 55 74 62 54 51 52 45 44 56 34 75 5c 6e   5PIUtbTQREDV4u\n
00f0   2b 4b 6f 55 75 6b 41 4c 71 6c 2f 42 42 6b 41 34   +KoUukALql/BBkA4
0100   76 67 6a 67 4f 55 45 30 79 53 74 36 74 77 61 79   vgjgOUE0ySt6tway
0110   6a 2b 6b 33 73 6e 6b 2f 56 70 49 6a 61 44 74 36   j+k3snk/VpIjaDt6
0120   32 6f 33 62 35 70 6e 44 4b 45 68 48 4c 56 45 66   2o3b5pnDKEhHLVEf
0130   5c 6e 79 6c 4a 30 6b 45 6e 58 4e 43 54 35 68 73   \nylJ0kEnXNCT5hs
0140   6b 64 68 39 66 59 38 78 74 6d 62 42 6d 57 31 47   kdh9fY8xtmbBmW1G
0150   2b 6e 54 6c 30 73 43 47 54 2f 75 75 77 65 31 6b   +nTl0sCGT/uuwe1k
0160   74 67 45 78 7a 70 43 67 57 77 62 75 71 78 49 49   tgExzpCgWwbuqxII
0170   47 54 5c 6e 66 63 58 31 79 52 6d 54 73 77 37 53   GT\nfcX1yRmTsw7S
0180   66 73 5a 71 58 4f 61 39 50 6f 36 62 68 65 73 48   fsZqXOa9Po6bhesH
0190   4e 78 4c 33 48 53 52 35 72 43 6f 73 6f 6f 72 75   NxL3HSR5rCosooru
01a0   34 7a 67 71 6a 6b 64 62 42 2f 57 2b 46 71 6d 35   4zgqjkdbB/W+Fqm5
01b0   42 6d 71 50 5c 6e 44 51 75 4c 6b 49 6c 4c 4a 2b   BmqP\nDQuLkIlLJ+
01c0   34 56 32 71 35 63 48 41 73 67 4d 54 38 48 52 78   4V2q5cHAsgMT8HRx
01d0   31 5a 74 50 75 55 54 78 45 49 66 55 49 4e 58 64   1ZtPuUTxEIfUINXd
01e0   41 57 67 4b 36 75 4d 75 4e 74 4d 4e 5a 56 4f 50   AWgK6uMuNtMNZVOP
01f0   6b 2f 71 54 31 30 5c 6e 72 51 49 44 41 51 41 42   k/qT10\nrQIDAQAB
0200   5c 6e 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 50 55 42 4c 49   \n-----END PUBLI
0210   43 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 5c 6e 22 7d 7d 00   C KEY-----\n"}}.
```

it goes out in intervals, till Camera replies back. I tried to imitate the packet and I was unsuccessful because I couldn't replicate these bytes (beginning of the Data frame):

(002B->003A): 02 00 00 01 01 e5 11 00 08 34 d4 be c1 46 b6 89

As you noticed immediately after this the ASCII readable message starts ({"params":...), I repeated the discovery steps few times and I noticed these bytes are somehow related to the local bound port on the app side that the udp discovery message is sent via, here are the examples I gathered:

```
Frame in udp packet                 port
0200000101e511000d554fad4de6fb2b    49411
0200000101e5110003ef2ad6767c88ee    49417
0200000101e511000c74622ed5e0246e    50248
0200000101e511000376feec3ed43466    50260
0200000101e51100046c5d74ee1a8de1    50797
0200000101e5110000503e7aa816e491    50802
0200000101e511000fdfc58e766d3742    52169
0200000101e511000e13aaabcd1a38ba    52332
0200000101e511000834d4bec146b689    52717
0200000101e511010000027822e38756    52956
0200000101e5110003e10659047571be    53370
0200000101e511000cbad8000079daf0    53500
0200000101e5110002e5bc217cb12739    57161
0200000101e511000922aa242d80ae84    58170
0200000101e511000d8945e5e21b2265    58421
0200000101e511000f97146569f2cbfe    58425
0200000101e511000d66c663c5ac4d69    59985
0200000101e511000105947d8d9e16f9    61818
0200000101e511000c9ed77f9024d65f    61879
0200000101e5110008b9a7fbc1624863    61927
0200000101e511000b3d5323ee84b6b7    62182
0200000101e511000f7b9b183a81ff80    62996
0200000101e511000da2e8028da2f46a    63043
0200000101e5110000c4390fbdc258e2    63046
```

I cannot find the relation, I tried few different IoT protocols and hashing methods, Does anybody know what are these or how are they calculated?

P.S.
Those port number are somehow coded inside those frames, it should be an industrial coding, simple hash or xor encryption. Any idea?

Comment: What's the one, focused question here? You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, as the current question sounds most like "What does all of this mean?"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app is generating an RSA public/private key pair and is broadcasting the public key within a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object.  The port in use has nothing to do with the key pair.  In fact, even if the *same* port is ever reused again, the key pair will still be different. If you want to know more about RSA, maybe start here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: I actually noticed that, but the UDP packet data starts at 002B, before the json object these bytes are added: 0200000101e511000d554fad4de6fb2b, in my tests I noticed by adding these bytes and set the port to the corresponding value, the camera replies back with it's own rsa public key. but if I leave those bytes empty, omit them or fill with different values, I get no answer.

Comment: The IP total length is 529 bytes (0x0211), so subtracting 20 bytes for the IP header length itself and 8 bytes for the UDP header, you end up with 501 bytes (0x01f5).  There looks to be 16 bytes for the payload header, so 501-16=485 (0x01e5), so the 5th and 6th bytes of those 16 bytes of payload is the length field in big-endian format.  Other bytes could be payload types, checksums, sequence numbers, who knows.

Comment: No idea if this packet format is exactly the same, but considering the PktLength matches what I discovered on my own, maybe Slide 37 of this document helps? https://www.troopers.de/downloads/troopers17/TR17_fgont_-iot_tp_link_hacking.pdf

Comment: Just got off work, those are brilliant, thank you. I'll try this evening and let you know, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

edit: This has stopped working - it may be that a firmware update was pushed to change what the plugs respond to? Unsure. Will investigate at some point.

It may be a late reply but I was recently working on this problem myself and can share what I figured out:

- The first four bytes are always 2, 0, 0, 1.
- The next two bytes are the length of the json bytestring that comes later, encoded as a two-byte number in big-endian.
- The next two bytes are 17 (11 in hex) and 0.
- The next 4 bytes are completely randomly generated - they can be anything. The Tapo android app that I examined to figure this out generated a random value from 0 to 268435456 and converted that to a 4-byte big-endian value for this purpose.
- The final step is a little trickier: insert the number 1516993677 encoded to a 4-byte big endian value, but then *overwrite* it with a crc32 checksum on the *whole* byte array (including the json on the end). That should give you a value that you can send and have tp-link smart plugs/cameras respond to.

[Here's](https://github.com/Levtastic/TapoP100/blob/0c705f667df8b117f6c4893a207ea757d0c27184/PyP100/tp_link_broadcast.py#L51-L84) a couple of python functions that I ended up using to generate these bytes in my own project:

```py
from random import randrange
from zlib import crc32
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def get_payload():
    key = RSA.generate(2048).publickey().exportKey('PEM')

    # newline on the end and no spaces in separators to perfectly match
    #  the packets sent by vendor apps
    payload = json.dumps(
        {'params': {'rsa_key': key.decode('utf-8') + '\n'}},
        separators=(',', ':')
    )

    # Fun fact: the P100 plugs will respond just the same if you send
    #  b'\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x11\x00\x0e\xd7\xd6\xac\x84\x0e\xfdY'
    #  which is the result of passing an empty string to build_packet()
    #
    # We send a full packet anyway, however, in case future firmware
    #  updates fix that
    return build_packet(payload)

def build_packet(string):
    # Magic prefix bytes generated by reverse-engineering the Tapo android app
    #  algorithm found in com\tplink\tdp\common\b.java
    prefix = b'\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Zk|\x8d'

    output_array = bytearray(prefix + string.encode('utf-8'))

    # Insert dynamic bytes that change based on the string / randomness
    output_array[4:6] = len(string).to_bytes(2, 'big')
    output_array[8:12] = randrange(268435456).to_bytes(4, 'big')

    # Insert checksum based on current array
    output_array[12:16] = crc32(output_array).to_bytes(4, 'big')

    return bytes(output_array)
```

(You can see a little more of how this was figured out in the commit history at the above link)